# how to send array variable from php to matlab?

Tags: php, arrays, matlab

I am making my final project, but I got stuck with this part.
I just want to send my array (2 dimensional array) to `matlab` function as parameter.
how can it be done?

Here is my `PHP` code to execute `matlab` function:

```
$command1 = "matlab -sd ".$inputDir." -r createNew($new)";
exec($command1);
```

In my `matlab` function it is supposed to be like this:

```
function createNew(new)
    display(new);
    %---some code here...---
end
```

I have tried different ways, but I can't get the value of array `$new`.

Comment: `$command1 = "matlab -sd ".$inputDir." -r createNew([1,2,3])";`. Would be the correct string for matlab. Not familiar with PHP how to generate the string from a variable.

Comment: $new is 2-dimensional array that already have some value. for example, $new index are [10][20]. so the array would be $new[10][20] and I want to passing it to matlab function..